# I am unable to locate this element, python selenium

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Tried it with class name and now XPath with no luck.
code =

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[@id='root']/div[@class='login-form']/div[@class='login-form-tabs']/div[@class='TabsNav_TabsNav__3uqOq tabs-nav']/div[@class='nav-link TabNavLink_TabNavLink__1Au2n']  ")))
signup = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[@id='root']/div[@class='login-form']/div[@class='login-form-tabs']/div[@class='TabsNav_TabsNav__3uqOq tabs-nav']/div[@class='nav-link TabNavLink_TabNavLink__1Au2n'] ")
signup.click()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\noahr\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\main.py", line 32, in <module>
    signup = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[@id='root']/div[@class='login-form']/div[@class='login-form-tabs']/div[@class='TabsNav_TabsNav__3uqOq tabs-nav']/div[@class='nav-link TabNavLink_TabNavLink__1Au2n'] ")
  File "C:\Users\noahr\.virtualenvs\pythonProject-ME1SVWk8\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Users\noahr\.virtualenvs\pythonProject-ME1SVWk8\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\noahr\.virtualenvs\pythonProject-ME1SVWk8\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\noahr\.virtualenvs\pythonProject-ME1SVWk8\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[@id='root']/div[@class='login-form']/div[@class='login-form-tabs']/div[@class='TabsNav_TabsNav__3uqOq tabs-nav']/div[@class='nav-link TabNavLink_TabNavLink__1Au2n'] "}
  (Session info: chrome=92.0.4515.159)
```

HTML structure:
[image]

Comment: Could you provide the link to the webpage as well

Comment: Which element is that in UI ?

Comment: https://fantasy5.com/football and click the login/singup button top right. the actual link too long @SPSharan

Comment: @cruisepandey my bad i gave wrong error lemme edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below xpath :

```
//span[text()='Login / Signup']/..
```

**code :**

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[text()='Sign Up']/..")))
element.click()
```

Comment: this is my fault for the misunderstanding. you click on the login signup button to get to the actual link i was talking about. I couldn't comment the link as it was too many characters.

Comment: @Noah Riley :- okay I think you can use `//span[text()='Sign Up']/..` xpath. Updated above as well.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```py
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class,'nav-link')][2]"))).click()
```